# MySQL - перенести значения из одной таблицы в другую

Tags: mysql

Здравствуйте!

Есть таблица с тремя колонками.

Table1:

```
       +------------+-------------------------------
       | id_model      | Type          |  id_model | 
       +------------+-------------------------------
       | 12            | Седан         |      34   |
       | 13            | Внедорожник   |      12   |
       | 14            | Универсал     |      23   |
       | 15            | Купе          |      44   |
       | 2032          | Седан         |      51   |
       +------------+-------------------------------
```

Мне нужно взять из этой таблицы значения `Type` и перенести в другую пустую таблицу с двумя колонками. В этой таблице id является `AUTO_INCREMENT` и значения этой колонки соответственно должны начинаться с единицы.

Table2:

```
       +---------+----------------
       | id      | Type          | 
       +---------+----------------
```

Пишу такой запрос:

```
INSERT INTO table2 SELECT type FROM table1 group by type
```

В ответ ошибка `column count doesn't match value count at row 1` - количество столбцов не совпадает с количеством значений в строке 1.

Что нужно сделать, чтобы количество столбцов совпадали и id во второй таблице принимали значения `AUTO_INCREMENT` начиная с единицы?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO Table2 (Type)
    SELECT Type FROM Table1;
```

Для автоинкремента (если он у Вас ещё не настроен), сделать таблицу с

```
ID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
```